# Gradle cannot find volley on maven

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-volley

I can't find the url on maven too build my project.
My android studio gives the following error:

```
Error:com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+ (double-click here to find usages.)
```

The whole build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 100
    versionName "1.00"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFile getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
    }
}
productFlavors {
    defaultFlavor {
        proguardFile 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
    maven {
        url 'http://clinker.47deg.com/nexus/content/groups/public'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3@jar'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.48@jar'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48@jar'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:extra-abc:+'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
    compile ('com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview:swipelistview:1.0-SNAPSHOT@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
}
```

As you see in the file I added mavenCentral() to the dependencies but that didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check you have the right repository declaration in your `build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: I tried to add that as you see above in my file but that didn't help

Comment: Could you put the full output of the command `./gradlew assembleDebug` ?

Comment: After watching at the console i found the error. It was in offline mode so now it works :)